# Pandas to pickle error - maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm new to Python and its pickle format.

So I came across an error message when I wrote to_pickle.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> old = pd.read_pickle('vol.pkl')
>>> old = old.append(updates)
>>> pd.to_pickle(old,'vol.pkl')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "\\\python-site-packages\win64_vc11\Lib\site-packages\pandas-0.13.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 15, in to_pickle
    pkl.dump(obj, f, protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "\\\python-site-packages\win64_vc11\Lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 664, in __getnewargs__
    return (unicode(self),)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Anyone knows why this happens and how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. What is self in this case? 2. do you use Python 2.7?

Comment: There may be another issue but I don't think you want `pd.to_pickle('vol.pkl')`. You want `old.to_pickle('vol.pkl')` or `pd.to_pickle(old,'vol.pkl')`

Comment: @User Yes I'm using 2.7.6. I don't get your first question..

Comment: @KarlD. Thanks I have revised it..

Comment: In the line `return (unicode(self),)`: waht is th value of the variable `self`?

Comment: @User I have no idea as return(unicode(self)) is mentioned in the error message and seems that it is a call inside element.py

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by adding a bs4.element.NavigableString element to the dataframe. Converting that to a string solved the issue!

The comment "In the line return (unicode(self),): what is the value of the variable self?" put me to the solution, thanks! I noticed the bs4\element.py in the error message. I realised that I was (accidently) also adding bs4 items to my dataframe. I incorrectly assumed that soup.title.string returned a string but it returned a type bs4.element.NavigableString.

```
    # the issue: type(title) = bs4.element.NavigableString

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in __getnewargs__(self)
    784 
    785     def __getnewargs__(self):
--> 786         return (str(self),)
    787 
    788     def __getattr__(self, attr):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Comment: Not only that, but you may find you have scrubbed all of the NavigableString objects out of the data area of the DataFrame, but don't forget the headings. In my case, I had added the NavigableString objects to the column headings. Do a `[type(c) for c in df.columns]` for your DataFrame (`df` in this case) to see the types.